# To submit the data only when the fields are changed in Angular

Tags: angular

I have an Angular form:

`<button mat-flat-button color="primary" [disabled]='Updateurlflag || !appawareform.dirty' *ngIf="title== 'Edit'" (click)="editappawareinfo(drawer)">Update</button>`

In my Edit drawer, there will be three fields. They are *Id*, *IP*, and *Port*. While editing, I disabled the field Id. The user can change only *IP*/*Port* or both.

If the user does not change any value in the Edit drawer, I disabled the button `Update`.

But the problem is if I erase 1 symbol in fields and then write it again (the value is the same, but form was changed),

I have to again disable the button `Update`. But how can I do this?

Comment: IP is a protocol; it is IP addresses that are static, filtered, blocked, assigned, bound, fetched, accessed, resolved, checked, banned, tracked, detected, dynamic, grabbed, scanned, whitelisted, have different representations, that devices have, etc., not the protocol itself.

Answer (score 4):

If you use ReactiveForms, it's easy control when a formControl change

Imagine you has a formControl with "updateOn:blur"

```
formControl=new FormControl('',{ updateOn: 'blur' });
```

You can subscribe to change using pairwise rxjs operator like

```
this.formControl.valueChanges.pipe(
 startWith(this.formControl.value), //it's necesary send a first value
 pairwise())  //the pairwise make the "magic"
 .subscribe(([old,value])=>{
    if (old!=value)
    {
       console.log("I change from "+old+" to "+value)
    }
 })
```

Well, I use a FormControl, you can use a FormGroup or a FormArray and subscribe to valueChanges

See a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eervhq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

You can store the previous value in an object and check whether the current value matches with the previous one. I'll write sample code below:

#### File `Component.ts`

```
previousValue: any = {};

previousValue = this.data; // Data fetched from the server.

isDisabled() {
  if(this.previousValue.ip === this.formGroup.ip && this.previousValue.port === this.formGroup.port) {
     return true;
   }

   return false;
}
```

#### File `Component.html`

```
<button mat-flat-button color="primary" [disabled]='isDisabled()' *ngIf="title== 'Edit'" (click)="editappawareinfo(drawer)">Update</button>
```

Comment: @Bear, I think it's more "confortable" using a pairwise rxjs operator, see my answer

Comment: @Eliseo, well, your solution works basically only once. what if the initial value is `myip` in the form, then user changes it to `myip1`, then user changes it to `myip2`, then user changes it back to `myip` (and each time leaves the field). Your solution will pass since it checks pairwise for `myip2` and `myip`, whereas OP wants to check if user has retyped the original value.

Answer (score 0):

If you having a reactive form (and if you don't, I suggest you do instead) Store the original value and compare it to the value of the form. If you don't have deeply nested object, you can safely use `JSON.stringify` to compare two objects. So do:

```
appawareform: FormGroup;
alive = true;
noChanges = true;

// maybe getting this from backend? Here just mocking the response
data = { id: 1, ip: "myip", port: "myPort" };

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.appawareform = this.fb.group({
    id: [{ value: "", disabled: true }],
    ip: [""],
    port: [""]
  });

  // call this when values are available
  this.appawareform.setValue(this.data);

  this.appawareform.valueChanges
    .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive))
    .subscribe(val => {
      if (
        JSON.stringify(this.data) ===
        // we have a disabled field we need to use "getRawValue()"
        JSON.stringify(this.appawareform.getRawValue())
      ) {
        this.noChanges = true;
      } else {
        this.noChanges = false;
      }
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  // unsubscribes subscrption on component destroy
  this.alive = false;
}
```

Check the status of the variable `noChanges` and disable or enable button based on that.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6jo6aj?file=src/app/app.component.html