# get old value and new value in input text using Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular

i am trying to get the old value and the new value in input text after focus.
I cant seem to find a way to get the data from the input only without focus. it gets the data each time i add a letter in the input and instead of getting the text when out of focus.
thanks

Comment: You can add a blur event listener if you want to fetch data when focus moves away from input. But please post your code so as to understand what the exact issue is

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-vhtxua

Comment: as you can see each time a letter is typed the new value is compared to the old where i need it would be compared onl when you move away from the input

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58831060/to-submit-the-data-only-when-the-fields-are-changed-in-angular/58832436#58832436

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to trigger your logic on `blur` event, add methods for corresponding events (`focus`-for storing initial value, `blur`-showing final value) and perform logic.

**Stackblitz**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-gnwg9p

Hope this helps!

Comment: Jins, why you abandon the idea of pairwise?. NOTE: use startWith(this.form.value.example1) and startWith(this.form.value.example2), not with "null"

Comment: I just thought in that way focused on event callbacks :) 
By using reactive forms also we can achieve that. Using `updateOn` property of `FormControl`. But its on Angular 5+ only.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-auycjc