# Store previous selected values in select box before on change event in angular forms

Tags: angular, forms, multidimensional-array, onchange

I have dynamic select boxes for different properties which get populated in the form. Before on change event I want to store the array of selected property values from the dropdown.
(properties => array with multiple dropdown values under a property)

```
<div *ngFor="let p of properties; let i = index">
    <ng-select placeholder="Select" (change)="onChange($event)">
            <ng-option *ngFor="let value of p.values" [value]="value">{{value.value}}</ng-option>
          </ng-select>
</div>
```

I tried using focus to store old value but its providing only current selected value.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So you want to store all the previously selected value and at the same time you also want currently selected value as well mean 2 variables which will contains prev and current values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit* - as Eliseo pointed out in the comments, you can use the [Pairwise](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/pairwise) operator to [make this even easier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58832436/821918).

The way I'd do this is to create a [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#addControl), iterate my properties list adding each control and then subscribe to each controls [ValueChanges](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges) observable. What's nice about `ValueChanges` is that the event triggers before the value is updated, so you can easily access the current value and what the value will be.

Here's an example:

```
export class AppComponent {
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
  previousValues = {};

  properties: any[] = [
    {
      label: "Favorite Animal",
      values: ["cat", "dog", "bird", "bunny"]
    },
    {
      label: "Favorite Vehicle",
      values: ["car", "boat", "motorcycle", "hot air balloon"]
    },
    {
      label: "Favorite Element",
      values: ["earth", "air", "fire", "water"]
    }
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.properties.forEach(prop => {
      this.form.addControl(prop.label, new FormControl(""));
      this.previousValues[prop.label] = "";

      this.form.controls[prop.label].valueChanges.subscribe(evt => {
        this.previousValues[prop.label] = this.form.value[prop.label];
      });
    });
  }
}
```

And the template:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" *ngFor="let p of properties; let i = index">
    <label>{{i}}: </label>
    <select placeHolder="Select" [formControlName]="p.label">
    <option [value]="opt" *ngFor="let opt of p.values">
      {{opt}}
    </option>
  </select>
</form>

<div class="form-value">
    <label>Current Values:</label>
    {{form.value | json}}
</div>

<div class="form-value">
    <label>Previous Values:</label>
    {{previousValues | json}}
</div>
```

[Here's a stackblitz that demonstrates.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mdlujd?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: spots, you can use pairwise in valuesChanges if you want to get the old and value:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58831060/to-submit-the-data-only-when-the-fields-are-changed-in-angular/58832436#58832436